# My view to login keeps saying that "User with this Email already exists."

Tags: django

I have a customized User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   email       = _models.EmailField     (max_length=252, unique=True)
   username    = _models.CharField      (max_length=252, blank=True, null=True)
   staff       = _models.BooleanField   (default=False)
   superuser   = _models.BooleanField   (default=False)
   active      = _models.BooleanField   (default=True)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

This is the form

```
class UserLoginForm(_f.ModelForm):
    password = _f.CharField(widget=_f.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

And this is the view

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import FormView,
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserLoginForm
class UserLoginView(FormView):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'accounts/user_login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request=self.request, email=email, password=password)

        if user:
            login(self.request, user)
            return super(UserLoginView, self).form_valid(form)

        return super(UserLoginView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

the `urls.py` of the app

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserLoginView, UserRegistrationView
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

the `urls.py` of the project

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('applications.accounts.urls', namespace='namespace_accounts')),
]
```

This the template `user_login.html` of the view `UserLoginView`

```
{% extends 'accounts/login_base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After registrating as new user, the user is redirected to the login page, with the credentials, the login keeps saying "User with this Email already exists."

Note: The `email` field on the model `User` is unique.

Is obvious that the login page is trying to make another registration somehow, and this "somehow" is what it's confusing me.

What could I possibly be doing to solve this "User with this Email already exists."?

Comment: Most likely a `POST` is being issued to the wrong view.

Comment: `User with this Email already exists` because actually, the user enters an email already in db, not correct?

Comment: @Lemayzeur, Yes indeed, but it's a login and not a registration, thus if the login does exists and the password is valid then the login must proceed to a success url.

Comment: Somewhere in your codes, something hits the model with this data...

Comment: @HenrikAndersson, Do you have some hint on how could I possibly check which view the `POST` is being issued?

Comment: Can you share your `urls.py` and your template?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson, Sure. Done.

Comment: the attribute `action` of your form, maybe it calls another view, can we see your template as well?

Comment: @Lemayzeur, Right. Added the template. One thing, my form doesn't have the `action` attribute. Maybe that's a problem.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson, I added the template as well.

Comment: of course, it's a problem, you should provide the `url`, or let it empty if the current view is the same that will receive post data

Comment: @Lemayzeur, I added to the form `action="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"`, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - authenticate() A user with that username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792734/django-authenticate-a-user-with-that-username-already-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the `UserLoginView` was trying to make another registration, that is, create a new user again, instead of authenticate and do the login. That was happening because my form inherited from `forms.ModelForm`; changing from `forms.ModelForm` to `forms.Form` solved the problem.

The credit goes to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42792796/2953385) which punched right at the problem!