# Django User with that username already exists

Tags: python, html, django, authentication

**My aim** - Trying to create an authentication system in Django, and allows user to signup again with same username if their account is not activated.

If an user try to register with a certain username and that username already exists then update that user with this current user.

**My Approach** - I have created a form using "UserCreationForm" and defining my own methods to validate the form, and allows the user even if username already exists but user.is_active = False.

Code

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    name = forms.CharField()
    institution = forms.CharField()

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        user = None
        try:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                print("is user active username", user.is_active)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            if not user:
                pass
            elif not user.is_active:
                pass
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This Username Already Exists")
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        return username

     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'institution', 'password1', 'password2')
```

views.py

```
from .forms import SignupForm
def regUser(form):
    '''
    It will save Django user and student.
    It recieves form.cleaned_data as argument
    '''
    print("reg user line 1")
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=form['username'],
                                     email=form['email'], 
                                     password=form['password1'],
                                     is_active=False,
                                    )
    # notice is_active = False, becuase we will activate account if user will
    # verify the email
    user.save()
    student = Student(user=user, name=form['name'], institution=form['institution'])
    student.save()
    return user

def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('accounts:home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = regUser(form.cleaned_data)
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('accounts/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user':user, 'domain':current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })

            mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'email_sent': True})
        else:
            for field in form:
                for error in field.errors:
                    messages.error(request, error)
            return redirect("accounts:signup")

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="default_value")


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="default_value")
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="default_value")

    def save(self):
        super().save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**My problem** - I am getting error " A user with that username already exists" I don't why and from where this error is coming when I am trying to created a new user with already registered username but it account is not activated yet (user.is_active = False).

As much I know clean_fields functions are called to validate the form when we use "form.is_valid()" in our views.py, But I have already overridden the "clean_username" according to my need so **why I am getting this error ? and from where it is generated ? and how to solve this ?**

Also I would like to mention when user is registered it is also registered "student" that's why I am using "regUser" function. Also I read some other questions similar to this on stackoverflow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792734/django-authenticate-a-user-with-that-username-already-exists) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588808/django-how-to-check-if-username-already-exists) some answer was that inherit the form from "forms.Form" not from "UserCreationForm" but why can anyone explain?

Please not mark this question as **already answered** I have gone through all questions and it was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The User model you defined inherited the `AbstactUser`, and `username` is defined there.

```py
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    ...
```

The attribute `unique` for `username` field means that username must be unique among **all users**, not only **active users**.
(ref. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique)

If what you want is to allow users to have the same username among inactive users, set unique=False.

But, if 'inactive' means 'discarded' in your `User` model, I would recommend changing user's `username` to garbage value when the user is being inactivated.